# Treating a bidimensional text (Ruzzle solver)

Tags: java, text, dictionary, matrix

I am trying to program a Ruzzle solver Java application for learning purpose.
I have a little problem in th ematter of "finding words" in a Ruzzle-type map.

Example of a Ruzzle map (it is composed of 4 rows and 4 columns of 1 letter in each cell) :

```
Z O O H
E Y L H
I E L I
H O F M
```

http://www.maclife.com/files/imagecache/futureus_imagegallery_fullsize/gallery/ruzzle1.jpg

I would like to obtain a list of all possible words you can find in such a map.

The difficulty : you can find a word by appending letters vertically, horizontally and diagonally (example : "HELLO").

So far, I created 3 classes :

- **Ruzzlesolver.java**
- **Letter.java**
- **Map.java**

## The Letter class

Describes a single Letter of the map, its fields are the X and Y positions and the character of the cell.

## The Ruzzlesolver class

This is the main class.

- it reads the *Ruzzle map* (an line by line input in the console)
- it reads the *dictionnary.txt* file
- it compares the map with the dictionnary file
- it writes into the *results.txt* file

Each line is stored in a char array.
Then I create a new Map object from the 4 obtained arrays.

## The Map class

This is the constructor of the Map objects :

```
public Map(final char[] pTab1, final char[] pTab2, final char[] pTab3, final char[] pTab4)
{
    this.aLettres = new ArrayList<Letter>();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
        this.aLettres.add(new Letter(1, i+1, pTab1[i]));}
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
        this.aLettres.add(new Letter(2, i+1, pTab2[i]));}
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
        this.aLettres.add(new Letter(3, i+1, pTab3[i]));}
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
        this.aLettres.add(new Letter(4, i+1, pTab4[i]));}
}
```

this.aLettres is the ArrayList that contains each of the 16 letters of the map.

Each Letter knows its column (X position : "i+1"), its row (Y position : "1, 2, 3 and 4") and its character ("pTab[i]").

Now that we know the map and the place of each letter, we can begin to find the words.

### The contains() method

This is my problem : I am stuck using the following method :

#### How it is called

1. I pick a word from the dictionnary in the Ruzzlesolver class.
2. I call the contains() method on my Map object, with this word as a parameter :

   ```
   if (this.aMap.contains(vMot)) {/*print vMot in the result.txt file*/}
   ```

#### How does the contains() method work

1. Variables :

   ```
       char[] vChars = new char[pMot.length()];
       ArrayList<Letter> vFoundCharS1 = new ArrayList<Letter>();
   ```
2. Stocking each characters of pMot in an ArrayList :

   ```
       for (int i = 0 ; i < pMot.length() ; i++) {
           vChars[i] = pMot.charAt(i);
       }
   ```
3. Searching for the first character of pMot :

   ```
       for (Letter vL : this.aLettres) {
           if (vL.getChar() == vChars[0]) {
               vFoundCharS1.add(vL);
               return true;
           }
       }
   ```
4. I am stuck.

If I continue this method, I will have to create longer and longer blocks as I progress. Besides, I would need to write 16 blocks to consider every length possibility.

I am sure this is a wrong method. How would you implement such a treatment ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

PS : I apologize for grammar/English mistakes, English is not my natal language.

Comment: Do you want this to be efficient or is brute force acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you can pick every adjacent cell for the next letter, right? In that case, the code below would (I think) solve your problem.

I changed the constructor of `Map`, because it is easier to work with a two-dimensional array of `char`.

The function `contains` does just what your step 3 described: find the first letter and try searching on from there. The function `findRecursively` searches for the rest of the word recursively.

```
public class Map {
    private char[][] board;

    public Map(final char[] pTab1, final char[] pTab2, 
           final char[] pTab3, final char[] pTab4) {
        board = new char[4][4];

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
            board[0][i] = pTab1(i);
            board[1][i] = pTab2(i);
            board[2][i] = pTab3(i);
            board[3][i] = pTab4(i);
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(String word) {
        char[] array = word.toCharArray();

        // empty string is trivial
        if (array.length == 0)
            return true;

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] == array[0] && findRecursively(i, j, array, 1))
                    return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean isValid(int i, int j) {
        return (0 <= i && i < 4) && (0 <= j && j < 4);
    }

    public boolean findRecursively(int i, int j, char[] array, int index) {
        // reached end of word
        if (index == array.length) {
            return true;
        } else {
            // loop over all neighbors
            for (int di = -1; di <= 1; di++) {
                for (int dj = -1; dj <= 1; dj++) {
                    // skip cell itself and invalid cells
                    if (!(di == 0 && dj == 0) && isValid(i+di, j+dj)) {
                        if (board[i+di][j+dj] == array[index] 
                              && findRecursively(i+di, j+dj, array, index+1))
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Your implementation looks very nice, I will give it a try tomorrow.
Thanks for your help, I'll tell you if it works for me.

Comment: Just be careful because this code does not forbid coming back to the same letter multiple times. You have to be sure the game allows this.

Comment: @AndréNeves You're right, I had to find a way to prevent the same cell to be read twice in one same word, using a two-dimensional array of booleans. I finished my program thanks to you two.